# Angular failed post request with error 500

Tags: json, angular, rest, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an ionic app that makes a rest call to a backend to send an email, when I make the rest call I get the following error, what can be due to (the rest call in postman works, I use chrome with the cors disabled)

**Error:**

```
POST http://172.16.50.92/send 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Code Angular:**

```
 const params = {
            'type': 'mail',
            'attributes[to_recipients]': mail,
            'attributes[body]': body,
            'attributes[subject]': subject,
            'attributes[attachments]': attachments
        };
         endpoint = url + '/send';
        
         var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
         headers_object.append('contentType', 'application/json');
         headers_object.append('Authorization', `Basic ${window.btoa(username + ':' + password)}`);
         return this.http.post(endpoint, params, [headers_object]);
```

Comment: Try `Content-Type` instead of `contentType`. Relevant [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Comment: i have try this solution but i have same error

Answer (score 0):

> return this.http.post(endpoint, params, [headers_object]);

You put your headers into an array. But the signature is supposed to be

```
post(url: string, body: any, options: { headers: HttpHeaders })
```

for your usecase.

Please change to below and try again.

```
return this.http.post(endpoint, params, { headers: headers_object });
```